# Public key cryptography tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, tagging

As far as I can tell, there are currently no tags related to public key cryptography ([public-key](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-key), [private-key](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/private-key), [public-key-cryptography](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-key-cryptography)), and I'm not able to add tags yet. Should these be added?

**Edit:** Or [rsa](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rsa), [dsa](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dsa), etc.

**Edit 2:** I guess I actually can create tags now, but I'll still wait for feedback here before I do.

Answer (score 1):

We do already have the [pki](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pki) tag and the [cryptography](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography) tag, which should cover off most requirements.

Comment: I agree, I don't think we need uber-specific tags per each algorithm (or even, family of algorithms). It's not like @Thomas is going to choose to answer one algorithm-tag, but not the other...